# Quadratic non-residue

Tags: number-theory

I'm reading "SQUARE FIBONACCI NUMBERS, ETC." by JOHN H.E. COHN. (http://math.la.asu.edu/~checkman/SquareFibonacci.html). There is a portion of it
in theorem 1 that I do not understand:

$L_n \text { is the nth term of the Lucas sequence} $.

k is any even integer that is not divisible by 3.

It is proven that $L_n \equiv -1 (\text{mod }L_k)$ 
and $L_k \equiv 3 (\text{mod } 4)$

The author concludes from the above that -1 is a non-residue of $L_k$.

From reading up on quadratic residues, all the methods of determining
if x is a non residue of p seem to depend on p being an odd prime. However in the above
case, $L_k$ is not always an odd prime. This is probably a trivial question, sorry in advance, I have read two textbooks on this and can find no way of proving that -1 is a 
non-residue of $L_k$

Thanks for any help

I can't answer my own question cause i'm new, here is the answer suggested by Gerry Myerson below.

> First off:
>
> If p is a prime number and p≡3(mod 4), then -1 is a non residue modulo
>   of p (law of quadratic reciprocity, first supplement)
>
> Then:
>
> Since n≡3(mod 4), n has a prime factor q for which q ≡3(mod 4). Since
>   q is a prime number and q≡3(mod 4), -1 is a non residue modulo of q.
>   Since n is a multiple of q, -1 is also a non residue modulo of n.

Comment: If $n\equiv3\pmod4$ then $n$ has a prime factor that is also 3 (mod 4). And $-1$ is a nonresidue modulo any such prime, hence, modulo $n$.

Comment: That's because it's a comment, not an answer. But if you understand it, you can write it up in your own words and post it as an answer, and then later you can accept it.

Comment: Okay sorry, i'm new to this.